# Method invoked on while verification of collection

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list `Q`. In the following code:

```
while Q:
    do_something()
    Q.pop()
```

in the `while Q` statement, what method of the list `Q` is invoked? Is it the `__len__` method?

Comment: Why would it be `len`? And `len` isn't a method of the list anyways. `__len__` would be the method.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it's __ len __ actually. The editor converted the "__" to bold. Thanks for the warning

Comment: Ahh. It's a good idea to wrap small code bits in backticks to prevent markup attempts. But again, why mention `__len__`? It may be called behind the scenes, but in this code snippet, `pop` is the method being called.

Comment: @Carcigenicate He's asking how `Q` is treated as a Boolean value, which could conceivably involve `__len__` being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.x, it's [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) or `__len__`:

> **`object.__bool__(self)`**
>
> Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation
>   `bool()`; should return `False` or `True`. When this method is not
>   defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is
>   considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither
>   `__len__()` nor `__bool__()`, all its instances are considered true.

In 2.x it was named [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__); see [what's new in 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods).

Answer (score 0):

From [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> - (...)
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - (...)
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or `bool` value `False`. [Additional information on these special methods may be found in the Python Reference Manual ([Basic customization](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customization)).]
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.
>
> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return `0` or `False` for false and `1` or `True` for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations `or` and `and` always return one of their operands.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `__len__` does get called in this case.

Let's see this code snippet:

```
class clist(list):

    def __len__(self):
        print "Called"

Q = clist([1,2,3,4])

while Q:
    break
```

Output:

```
Called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 10, in <module>
    while Q:
TypeError: an integer is required
```

But, if I remove the method,

```
class clist(list):
    pass

Q = clist([1,2,3,4])

while Q:
    break
```

the code will run just fine, but won't print anything.

So yes, `__len__` does get called.